# How can I log information to a dividual file by Nlog?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I am about to log information of the Spider in some `IActionResult` to a dividual file with the date.

For example:
C:\20210317spider.txt
C:\20210318spider.txt
C:\20210319spider.txt

I don't want to use some method such as `Logger.LogInformation` to log all information into a file.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [${shortdate}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ShortDate-Layout-Renderer) layoutrenderer inside the `FileName`-Layout for the NLog FileTarget:

```
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target type="file" name="spiderFile" fileName="C:/${shortdate}spider.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Spider" writeTo="spiderFile" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

See also the [NLog Tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) and the list of [available layoutrenders](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers) that can be used with NLog Layout.

Then you can do this with Microsoft [ILoggerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory):

```
public class MyClass
{
     private readonly ILogger _spiderLogger;

     public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
         _spiderLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Spider");
         _spiderLogger.LogInformation("Hello little spider");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, there are several targets in the targets element also and I need them to log the normal information also. Now the problem is I don't know how to order different targets by code.

Comment: @MelonNG Then I guess you should think of improving the details of your question. Maybe include the existing NLog.config, and what you tried already.

Comment: @MelonNG The normal approach for log-filtering is using the Logger-name. Ex. `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger("loggername")` and use the Logger-name in the `<rules>`-section.

Comment: @MelonNG Added some more detail to my answer, so the Logger-name becomes very specific and will not affect other targets.

Comment: I am sorry for busing these days. The code works well. Thank you so much.